# How use data in table as entity for key value in SQL?

Tags: sql, select

I have a table as following:

[image]

Is there any SELECT query to show table in following form?

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I dont think this has any relation to jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following code :

```
SELECT post_id,
       (SELECT meta_value from test where meta_key='_total') AS _total,
       (SELECT meta_value from test where meta_key='_phone') AS _phone,
       (SELECT meta_value from test where meta_key='_address') AS _address 
FROM test
GROUP BY post_id
```

UPDATE
Since the table is containing more post_id's, please check the following update.

```
SELECT post_id,
       (SELECT meta_value from test t2 where meta_key='_total' AND t1.post_id=t2.post_id) AS _total,
       (SELECT meta_value from test t2 where meta_key='_phone' AND t1.post_id=t2.post_id) AS _phone,
       (SELECT meta_value from test t2 where meta_key='_address' AND t1.post_id=t2.post_id) AS _address
FROM test t1
GROUP BY post_id
```

Comment: It returns error
subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: @WebDesign, I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: I want JOIN the out put your query with another table, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think accessing the same table four times is not needed.

You can use the `conditional aggregation` as follows:

```
SELECT post_id,
       max(case when meta_key='_total' then meta_value end) AS _total,
       max(case when meta_key='_phone' then meta_value end) AS _phone,
       max(case when meta_key='_address' then meta_value end) AS _address 
FROM test
GROUP BY post_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check this out too.